# Heroku application on deploy fails. Cannot find modules, but locally works

Tags: node.js, heroku

Pastebin with heroku logs: https://pastebin.com/MNEisZJA

```
let SerializedUser = require('./src/structures/models/SerializedUser.js');
let loginUser = require('./src/structures/functions/loginUser.js')
let resetPassword = require('./src/structures/functions/resetPassword.js')
let createUser = require('./src/structures/functions/createUser.js')
```

problem: works fine locally, is able to require the files successfully, but when i deploy to heroku it can't find the module.

Comment: How did you exactly deploy the heroku? Which guide did you follow?

Comment: I just connected it to my github repo and had it deploy my master branch. Worked completely fine doing this for another project, only difference is in the other project i did not require other files that were in the repo.

Comment: The error message seems clear enough... are the src files in the repo?  Both github AND heroku?

Answer (score 0):

check cases. for example having `v3.js` module:

```
require('./V3.js')
```

works on Mac, but doesn't work in ubuntu. So you should go with this instead

```
require('./v3.js')
```